# Unable to upgrade client from ActiveMQ 5.5.1 to ActiveMQ 5.10

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I'm unable to upgrade client from ActiveMQ 5.5.1 to ActiveMQ 5.10, activemq keeps ignoring my settings and tries to connect to default 'localhost' on port '61616'.

Here is my ActiveMQ Maven dependencies that was working fine

> ```
>    <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
>         <version>5.5.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-optional</artifactId>
>         <version>5.5.1</version>
>         <exclusions>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
>             </exclusion>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
>             </exclusion>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>
>             </exclusion>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
>             </exclusion>
>         </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
>         <version>5.5.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
>         <version>5.5.1</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Here is my new ActiveMQ 5.10 that is not working

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
>         <version>5.10.0</version>
>     </dependency> 
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
>         <version>5.10.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
>         <version>5.10.0</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Here is my spring.xml settings for ActiveMQConnectionFctory

> ```
>  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
>     <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(ssl://${jms.broker.host}:${jms.broker.ssl.port})?timeout=5000"/>
>    </bean>
> ```

for whatever reason the ActiveMQ 5.10 keeps trying to connect to localhost\61616. even though my variables ${jms.broker.host}:${jms.broker.ssl.port} dont point to localhost/61616.

The error i keep getting is

> 18:01:54.267 [ActiveMQ Task-1] WARN  o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

Also, ActiveMQ is integrated with spring and apache camel.

am i missing a dependency, or ActiveMQConnectionFactory can't be used anymore with ActiveMQ 5.10?

Thanks.

---

Issue resolved:

Bean 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory' was not created because property 'maximumActive' doesn't exist anymore, just had to use the new one.

Answer (score 0):

ssue resolved:

Bean 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory' was not created because property 'maximumActive' doesn't exist anymore, just had to use the new one.

Comment: Can you describe your solution in more detail? I didn't understand this `'maximumActive' doesn't exist anymore, just had to use the new one`